# Starting an Activity from Notification destroys Parent Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-notifications

I have an app with 4 activities int the sequence say **A->B->C->D** and a service **S** that is started by **A** when the app is started. Now on a particular condition this service triggers a notification which again should start activity **C** withing my app and with the arguments that **C** usually needs from **B**. Also to function properly, **C needs to use a static variable from the activity A**. That was the setup.

Now what happens is when the notification is triggered from the service **S** and I click on it, activities **A** and **B** are automatically destroyed resulting in a force close(Since my activity **C** depends on a **static variable in A**). Why does this happen. I have used a `TaskStackBuilder` to place **C's** parent activity(i.e **B**) onto the stack so that normal back behavior takes me back to activity **B**.

Can anyone tell me the reason of this behavior. I **do not** want to run my Activity **C** as an interdependent task. I want it to be the same instance as that already in the app.
Please help me understand the problem here.

Comment: Add Some Code so that some one be able to find the problem

Comment: too messed up.! not getting the real problem.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj when I click the notification to start activity C, it is destroying my Acivites A and B. That is the problem

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj In the normal workflow activity B starts the activity C

Comment: @Ricky What flags are you using to start activity C from B. Is it something like **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**.? what do you exactly mean by _Destroying_.? Does it means force close or just activity termination.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj I did not use any flag as such, I meant activity termination, onDestroy for activity B is being called. The normal flow  of the application is as such A starts B and then B starts C. Now depending upon some error checking an Android Notification can also start C, when this is happening activity B and A's onDestroy methods are being called.

Comment: You need to check the intent used to show **Notification**. I doubt it might be responsible for it, something like **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** or something that is destroying the previous activities. But it is still impossible to tell the error without looking at the code.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj I figured out that this is because the Activity Lifecycle behaves differenty from ICS onwards I have placed a new question with sample code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441951/activity-lifecycle-behaves-differently-jellybean-onwards . Please let me know

Comment: okay, let me have a look at it. But I dont think thid behaviour might be due to different android versions.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj.. Ok, please let me know what you think, as I could find only that one thing to be differing in two executions of the same application. I also tried it with two versions of the emulator and found the same behavior, this is exactly what puzzled me, eagerly waiting for your observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the Activity Lifecycle behaves differenty from ICS onwards. This fact answers this question, however I am yet to find out why this is happening. If someone wants to see the code and verify this behavior for themselves, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441951/activity-lifecycle-behaves-differently-jellybean-onwards)

Answer (score 2):

1. Activity should be independent. It is dangerous that *`activity C needs to use a static variable from the activity A`*. Although you create activities in order like **A->B->C->D**, Android may destroy A/B/C/D when your app is in background, and when user returns to your app, only activity D is recreated.
2. I encountered the same problem as you once, *`Starting an Activity from Notification destroys Parent Acitivities`*. This is because I used TaskStackBuilder. And even after I stop to use TaskStackBuilder, the problem remains. Only after I uninstall the app, it works as expected.
   Check the comments for https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268331/1198666