# Activity Lifecycle behaves differently JellyBean onwards

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I have the following scenario. Activity A starts Activity B. B starts a Notification clicking on which another activity C is started. Now the behaviour is different on Gingerbread and ICS onwards. Incase of Gingerbread when I click on the Notification, the expected behavior is seen, however when I run the same code on ICS or JellyBean when I click on the Notification Activity A is destroyed(OnDestroy is called). Why is the lifecycle behavior different. How can I make it to behave in a consistent way in all devices? Please suggest.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.v("MyLog","Activity A created");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.v("MyLog","Activity A destroyed");

        }
        public void startB(View v)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),B.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        protected void onStop()
        {
            super.onStop();
            Log.v("MyLog","Activity A stopped");
        }

        protected void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();
            Log.v("MyLog","Activity A resumed");
        }


    }
}

public class B extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b);
        Log.v("MyLog","Activity B created");
    }

    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        Log.v("MyLog","Activity B stopped");
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("MyLog","Activity B resumed");
    }

    public void startNotification(View v)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setAutoCancel(true);



        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(C.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        int mId=1;
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}

public class C extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.c);
        Log.v("MyLog","Activity C created");
    }
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        Log.v("MyLog","Activity C stopped");
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("MyLog","Activity C resumed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System can terminate activity always when it's needed. Probably it's not exectly difference between Android releases, but differece between different devices / free memory amount of different Android versions runing.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but then I can expect it to behave differently sometimes atleast, but I get the exact same result everytime, I have verified the same with two versions of emulators too, one created with android 2.3.3 and the other with 4.1.2. The Activity A is destroyed each in the 4.1.2 device/emulator. There is no mention of this behavior on the Developers Guide. That is what puzzles me.

Comment: You may verify the same with the code that I have posted, please let me know if you observe the same thing.

Comment: I don't know "why" - sorry. Docs say, that everything in background can be killed at any moment, including foreground services. Don't you use some big bitmaps in your layout, or some other large memory objects?

Comment: Nope nothing like that, just a simple TextView and a Button, Yes I am aware the docs say it "can" be killed but the case I am referring to is more of a "will" be killed as it is happening every single time. Its consistent behavior